# What if I didn't turn off all caching under General Settings before deleting the plugin w3 total cache

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

I installed the plugin W3 total cache but It crashed my website, so I had to delete it. The problem is that my site is still running. But I think I didn't delet it properly. I just renamed the folder of the plugin in the wp-content.

Another thing I did, I deleted the three files from the ftp : db.php, advanced-cache.php and object-cache.php

I didn't follow the instruction for delete the plugin and **I didn't unchecked all options**, disable and delete the plugin.

Is there any consequences and can I correct that?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Usually renaming the folder does deactivate plugins as the folder is no longer detected. Some plugins however create files and database tables which will remain after this so you should always follow the recommended deactivation/uninstallation suggested by the developer. You can find a reply from the developer to a question similar to yours here - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/impossible-to-uninstall-completely/